# Align "Withdraw" button to the left in Qualtrics using css

Tags: css

I need to insert a button that allows my participants to withdraw from my study at any time they want.

I have found a css code to insert the "withdraw" button on every page. However, this "Withdraw" button is located next to the "Next" button, and i don't want my participants to press it by mistake and exit the survey.
 This is the code i am using in the footer of Qualtrics:

```js
var inject_me = function() {
  if (!$("#NextButton").length) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(inject_me());
  } else {
    var element = document.getElementById('toggle');
    if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
      document.getElementById('ProgressBar').style.display = "none";
    } else {
      function addParameterToURL(param) {
        _url = location.href;
        _url += (_url.split('?')[1] ? '&' : '?') + param;
        return _url;
      }
      newURL = addParameterToURL("withdraw=true");

      var withdraw = "<a href=\"" + newURL + "\" onclick=\"javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to withdraw?')\" class=confirm id='WithdrawLink'><span class='ButtonLeft'></span><span class='WithdrawButton Button' id='WithdrawButton'>WITHDRAW</span><span class='Button' style='float:left !important'></span></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;"
      var buttonsDiv = document.getElementById("Buttons");

      buttonsDiv.innerHTML = withdraw + buttonsDiv.innerHTML;
    }
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("EndOfSurvey").length) {
      document.getElementById('Withdraw').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('ProgressBar').style.display = "none";
    }
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("SurveyError").length) {
      document.getElementById('Withdraw').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
inject_me();
```

```css
/* Place your CSS here */

.Skin #Buttons #WithdrawButton {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  transition: background .3s;
  background-color: #900;
  opacity: .25;
}

#WithdrawLink {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[this is how the page looks with both buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgfkR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the flexbox method. I hope the below code works.

```
.Skin #Buttons #WithdrawButton {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! That didn't work. However i have found several codes on here and have managed to create a button on the bottom left side of the page. I just need to  link it to a certain page (Debrief sheet) in my project. What could i use to do that? (Redirect participants to the end page if they choose to exit the survey).

Comment: i think you are already using <a></a> as button.You can give <a href="http:www.google.com"></a> like this.I hope this will work or you can check routing documentation of specific framework which you are using. @Melinda-RoxanaSuciu